# How can I remove BIOS unknown password on HP 620 laptop

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, 64-bit, bios, virtualization

While installing a new virtual machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) I got a message saying :

> This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.
>   This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
>   Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

I forgot my BIOS password that I put a long time ago (and didn't use it at all). I'm trying to access the BIOS since more than a week using different software and methods to remove or reinitialize the BIOS password. None worked.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You said you have tried a few methods. What are they?

Comment: I tried to remove the CMOS battery. I held the power button for more than 30 seconds while the battery and the CMOS battery were removed. I didn't find where the jumper is on the motherboard (if it exist).

Answer (score 3):

Well removing the CMOS battery is a good Idea but if you really want to bypass the Bios you can try and use one of the following things:

- Remove the CMOS Battery as stated above.
- Download this Tool: [BIOS320.EXE](http://www.technibble.com/downloads/misc/BIOS320.EXE) ***Note: This Tool only works with 32bit Operating Systems!*** 
  !BIOS is a freeware utility which is designed to be a whole BIOS and security suite. It has the ability to decrypt the passwords used in some of the most common BIOS makes such as Award, Phoenix, American Megatrends, IMB etc..
  It also has the ability to brute force the password (known as “blasters”). However, this method is dangerous and can result in some unexpected and unwanted results.
  Note: Because of this applications password cracking abilities, some antivirus software may report it as a virus/trojan. This is a false positive.
  To start using !BIOS, reboot your computer and take note of the BIOS type and version you are running. For example, If your motherboard uses Award BIOS you should look for the text “Award Medallion BIOS 6.0″ or something similar.
- You can Try and use one of the following Backdoor Passwords: 
  On many computers (especially old ones), computer manufacturers build in backdoor passwords for their own technicians to use so they can access the BIOS when the hardware is being serviced. Here are some of the ones that have been reported. You may need to try quite a few passwords before you find one that works
  These passwords are CaSe SeNsItIve.

```
AMI BIOS Backdoor Passwords:
A.M.I.
AAAMMMII
AMI
AMI?SW
AMI_SW
BIOS
CONDO
HEWITT RAND
LKWPETER
MI
Oder
PASSWORD


Award BIOS Backdoor Passwords:
(eight spaces)
01322222
589589
589721
595595
598598
ALFAROME
ALLY
ALLy
aLLY
aLLy
aPAf
award
AWARD PW
AWARD SW
AWARD?SW
AWARD_PW
AWARD_SW
AWKWARD
awkward
IOSTAR
CONCAT
CONDO
Condo
condo
d8on
djonet
HLT
J256
J262
j262
j322
j332
J64
KDD
LKWPETER
Lkwpeter
PINT
pint
SER
SKY_FOXSYXZ
SKY_FOX
syxz
SYXZ
TTPTHA
ZAAAADA
ZAAADA
ZBAAACA
ZJAAADC


Russian Award BIOS Passwords:
%øåñòü ïpîáåëîâ%
%äåâÿòü ïpîáåëîâ%


Phoenix Backdoor BIOS Passwords:
BIOS
CMOS
phoenix
PHOENIX


Other Manufcaturers Backdoor Passwords: (manufacturer name – password)
VOBIS and IBM – merlin
Dell – Dell
Biostar – Biostar
Compaq – Compaq
Enox – xo11nE
Epox – central
Freetech – Posterie
IWill – iwill
Jetway – spooml
Packard Bell – bell9
QDI – QDI
Siemens – SKY_FOX
SOYO – SY_MB
TMC – BIGO
Toshiba – Toshiba
```

Source: [How to Bypass or Remove a BIOS Password](http://www.technibble.com/how-to-bypass-or-remove-a-bios-password/)

Comment: Hi,
I've already tried these passwords, none of them worked!
@Ramhound it is Foxconn. it doesn't contain a jumper
I tried !BIOS and BIOS320.exe maybe i didn't know how to use it

Comment: Hmm worked with my old Compaq 6710b... Did you run BIOS320.exe from the cmd? Save the BIOS320.exe on your Desktop and open a cmd window by pressing the start key and then type in cmd and hit enter. If your running a 64bit Operating System its not going to work.