# How to enable virtualization without using bios?

Tags: bios, android, hardware-acceleration

I am using android studio.I want to run my app on simulator but it is asking me to install `intel haxm`,.When i install intel haxm it says that vitualization is not enabled/.To enable virtualization i need to goto bios but issue my bios is password protected & i don't know password.So please tell me is there any other way by which i can enable the virtualization without going into bios?

Comment: **You can't**.  If virtualization is disabled then you must enable it, form within BIOS, before you can use it.

Comment: Please don't publish basically the same Q every few minutes without even having used a search engine.

Comment: When you buy a new box, be sure to confirm that both the CPU and the motherboard support virtualization extensions. If both components don't support them, there is no way to make the extensions available on that hardware.

Answer (score 4):

**You can only enable this setting in the BIOS**

If you dont know your BIOS password, but you can get to your motherboard you may be able to reset the password or, a more brutal option, reset your BIOS.

**Power down your machine before attempting these!**

Depending on your board there are ways of reseting the password, some involve removing a small plastic tab, others have switches or jumpers. Consult your motherboard manufactuer for this.

If you have no other special settings in the BIOS removal of the small watch battery on the board for around 5-10 minutes, then re-inserting will reset the BIOS to factory defaults (The internal clock will be wiped and you will need to set this again too), This will clear your BIOS password and **you will be able to change the virtualisation setting**.

Note: Depending on your computer make/model, you may not have this style of BIOS battery. You should consult the user manual, or the service manual for your make/model to locate and determine if the CMOS/BIOS battery is of the removable kind.

Perhaps check out this other existing SU question:

- [How can I remove BIOS unknown password on HP 620 laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/621327/how-can-i-remove-bios-unknown-password-on-hp-620-laptop)

(OP's laptop model was discerned from another, related question posted by the same OP)